# Google Apps Script - TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I've copied another developer's code from Youtube. It extracts data from a Google Sheet and creates multiple PDFs. I understand Python better than Javascript, hence my question.

The code is as follows:

```
function createBulkPDFs() {
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("###");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DoE");
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, (currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4), 9);
  data.forEach(row => {
    createPDF(row[1], row[2], row[3], row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder, row[1] + " " + row[2]);
  });
}
```

I've read on the other threads that row => should not be used, but this video was created in April 2020, so I thought it was up-to-date programming. I realise it doesn't show in the auto-text dropdown when I click data.

I want to iterate through each of the rows in a Google Sheet.

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue of `TypeError: data.forEach is not a function` is due to that you are trying to use the Range object as an array. `getRange` returns the Range object. In your case, please modify `const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,(currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4),9);` to `const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,(currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4),9).getValues();` or `).getDisplayValues();`. By the way, I'm not sure about `createPDF`. So I'm not sure whether your script works without errors after you modified above. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for being creative. Neither solution worked.

Comment: I just retyped all the code. It must have been a syntax error. Thanks for anyone else who may have looked!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Neither solution worked.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. When you modified `const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,(currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4),9);` to `const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,(currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4),9).getValues();`, the same error of `TypeError: data.forEach is not a function` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue comes from the declaration of the constant `data`. When you say

> const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,(currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4),9)

As the above function only takes 4 parameters. See [`Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

When simplifying your `data` it becomes:

`currentSheet.getRange(2,1,x,4,9)` where "x" is `currentSheet.getLastRow()-1`.

To fix this you should only pass the 4 parameters that `getRange` expects.